# Count based on a date condition in PLSQLDev

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help to do a count based on a date condition.

I have a DB similar to the following:
[ManDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSVss.png)

| ID | report_date | traffic_v | traffic_ul | traffic_dl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1/12/2021 | 0 | **0** | 100 |
| a | 2/12/2021 | 0 | **0** | 100 |
| a | 3/12/2021 | 100 | **0** | 100 |
| a | 4/12/2021 | 100 | **0** | 100 |
| b | 1/12/2021 | 0 | 100 | 100 |
| b | 2/12/2021 | 0 | 0 | **0** |
| b | 3/12/2021 | 0 | 100 | **0** |
| b | 4/12/2021 | 100 | 100 | **0** |

I need you to count the data to zero, for which I have the query:

```
SELECT
  ID AS SECTOR,
  SUM(TRAFFIC) TRAFICO_VOZ,
  SUM(TRAFFIC_DL_G) + SUM(TRAFFIC_DL_E) TRAFFIC_DL,
  SUM(TRAFFIC_UL_G) + SUM(TRAFFIC_UL_E) TRAFFIC_UL
  FROM
  MainDB
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING SUM(TRAFFIC) = 0 
         OR (SUM(TRAFFIC_DL_G) + SUM(TRAFFIC_DL_E)) = 0
         OR (SUM(TRAFFIC_UL_G) + SUM(TRAFFIC_UL_E)) = 0
```

But I need you to count me from the current date backwards, how many days has it been zero

You should only count me from the last record in zero.
So you should get the following result:

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUE37.png)

| ID | traffic_v | count_v | traffic_ul | count_ul | traffic_dl | count_dl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 200 | 0 | **0** | **4** | 400 | 0 |
| b | 100 | 0 | 200 | 0 | **0** | **3** |

*I do not know how to set the condition so that it detects the date on which I began to have zero records and perform the count of days until the current date.
In cases where the register is different from zero, the count must be restarted.*

The db is updated daily.

the counts are displayed correctly with the query, as I only care about zero data.

try to use SUM / CASE, but it counts me from the minimum date that it finds at zero, regardless of having a different record

Comment: PL/SQL is the dialect for Oracle, *not* SQL Server (which uses T-SQL).

Comment: Please read about presenting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with your issues, but **it is not a code writing service**. Take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to review [ask]. Specifically here post your attempted query to do the counting and what the results of it are.

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language, but I don't see a programming problem here. PL/SQL Developer is a desktop application, but I don't see what issue you are having using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT id,
       count_traffic_v,
       sum_traffic_v,
       count_traffic_ul,
       sum_traffic_ul,
       count_traffic_dl,
       sum_traffic_dl
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   (
    SELECT m.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY report_date DESC) AS rn
    FROM   mainDB m
 )
  MODEL
    PARTITION BY (id)
    DIMENSION BY (report_date)
    MEASURES (
      rn,
      traffic_v,
      0 AS count_traffic_v,
      0 AS sum_traffic_v,
      traffic_ul,
      0 AS count_traffic_ul,
      0 AS sum_traffic_ul,
      traffic_dl,
      0 AS count_traffic_dl,
      0 AS sum_traffic_dl
    )
    RULES AUTOMATIC ORDER (
      count_traffic_v[report_date]  = CASE traffic_v[cv()]
                                      WHEN 0
                                      THEN COALESCE(count_traffic_v[cv() - 1] + 1, 1)
                                      ELSE 0
                                      END,
      sum_traffic_v[report_date]    = CASE traffic_v[cv()]
                                      WHEN 0
                                      THEN 0
                                      ELSE COALESCE(sum_traffic_v[cv() - 1], 0) + traffic_v[cv()]
                                      END,
      count_traffic_ul[report_date] = CASE traffic_ul[cv()]
                                      WHEN 0
                                      THEN COALESCE(count_traffic_ul[cv() - 1] + 1, 1)
                                      ELSE 0
                                      END,
      sum_traffic_ul[report_date]   = CASE traffic_ul[cv()]
                                      WHEN 0
                                      THEN 0
                                      ELSE COALESCE(sum_traffic_ul[cv() - 1], 0) + traffic_ul[cv()]
                                      END,
      count_traffic_dl[report_date] = CASE traffic_dl[cv()]
                                      WHEN 0
                                      THEN COALESCE(count_traffic_dl[cv() - 1] + 1, 1)
                                      ELSE 0
                                      END,
      sum_traffic_dl[report_date]   = CASE traffic_dl[cv()]
                                      WHEN 0
                                      THEN 0
                                      ELSE COALESCE(sum_traffic_dl[cv() - 1], 0) + traffic_dl[cv()]
                                      END
    )
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE maindb (ID, report_date, traffic_v, traffic_ul, traffic_dl) AS
SELECT 'a', DATE '2021-12-01',   0,   0, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', DATE '2021-12-02',   0,   0, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', DATE '2021-12-03', 100,   0, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', DATE '2021-12-04', 100,   0, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', DATE '2021-12-01',   0, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', DATE '2021-12-02',   0,   0,   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', DATE '2021-12-03',   0, 100,   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', DATE '2021-12-04', 100, 100,   0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | COUNT_TRAFFIC_V | SUM_TRAFFIC_V | COUNT_TRAFFIC_UL | SUM_TRAFFIC_UL | COUNT_TRAFFIC_DL | SUM_TRAFFIC_DL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | a | 0 | 200 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 400 |
> | b | 0 | 100 | 0 | 200 | 3 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a7ef28158a3d2b69f7a2e989217dd5d4)*